# Hide hostname in Tor

Tags: anonymity

I don't want that the website I am visiting knows I am using tor. Is it possible to hide the hostname, as this one mentions tor (see below)?

[image]

Comment: Different question, same answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't block a reverse DNS lookup on **remote website's server**, and - even if you could - beleive me, that just processing a webserver's log to extract IP addresses takes only some strings of shell scripting medium class. And you can not prevent that =) And - if the IP's will be shown from log - they can be compared to Tor Exit Nodes lists, they're not top secret.